# Firebase A/B testing: should you run two A/B experiments at once (with 2 variables each), or one A/B experiment with 4 variables?

Tags: firebase-ab-testing

Would there be any statistical difference between the following:

- Experiment 1:

  Baseline

  Remote config A changed
- Experiment 2:

  Baseline

  Remote config B changed

or

- Experiment 1

  Baseline

  Remote config A changed

  Remote config B changed

  Remote config A changed + Remote config B changed

Both remote config A and B have a very different effect on the app and user experience, so they are not connected.